# why my URL is changes when i fill the login details in mvc appliaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my application which is working on http as expected, But in Https 
request not working. 
- when i request for login page it is showing but after filling the 
login details "https://www.fhpl.net/tangoe" click submit the URL of the page is changed to 
"https://www.fhpl.net/tangoe?username=zxcXZ&password=zxcXZc&as_sfid=AAAAAAX97TGVNRLL68F9G0P9IxhP1vNZ5TCCeFoIkm8RUqzwqEmmuZqDudqe_RogJTFsePMHIYrVv60B58Xkz1efVbqHiuCylbc3aOBZWHzGrD-YZnGZ-VznYZ1Zs04O13XDNHs%3D&as_fid=3270f9977aa3fc2832d617f7da5f9e4edde75751"

Why this is happen, Please help us. i am unable to find the issue.

Comment: Could you add some code for the controller and the form?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you don't have a method "POST" specified on form.
That's why browser serializes your form into query string.
By default the method is "GET"